# Sqlite3 query problems when migrating to Python 3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 db that I am using with my Python app. I have decided to migrate from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7. The db I have has a table `inbox` that contains a binary string as an identifier (`msgID`).

The following query used to work in Python 2.7

```
SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE msgID=:msgID;
```

Where msgID is a binary string such as b'\x7f\xa1\x1a8\x18\xeb_X\xb1M\xd9\n\xb0\xf4\xd8\xbb'.
Now, with the upgrade that query is not returning any result, but translating the binary data into hex format seems to be working correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE hex(msgID)='7FA11A3818EB5F58B14DD90AB0F4D8BB';
```

With `7FA11A3818EB5F58B14DD90AB0F4D8BB = msgID.hex().upper()`. Any insights on why this is happening?

Comment: What is the type of the `msgID` column in the table?

Comment: It is in `BLOB` format. Could it be a problem on how data was inserted on Python 2? I noticed that other thread suggest casting the binary data into `buffer` or using `sqlite3.Binary` for insertion.

Comment: It would help to see how the data was inserted and retrieved in Python2.